# Get the Y position of "position: fixed" element with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, position

Is there any way to get the current Y position of an element that has "position: fixed" set in CSS? I just need to know the distance that this element is away from the top of the document in any way that uses pure javascript.

If that is not possible, I want to know why it is not possible in terms of logic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `offsetTop` property.

```js
var d = document.querySelector('div');
console.log(d.offsetTop);
```

```css
div{
  position:fixed;
  top:50px;
  background:red;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: That won't give the correct position I want as it will always return 50, but it helped me see that it will always return the current top css position (I thought it would literally always return 50, even if I changed to `top: 100px`), so I can just sum that to the current window.scrollY to get the element's position :) Thanks